# Uploding file to amazon s3 bucket through form using node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, signature, serverless, bucket

I am new to aws technology so i need suggestions to upload file to s3 bucket using node.js, so in order to complete above task what are the technologies and tools should i know.

Note: Without using AWS management console

My requirements are:

Windows 7
VS code 
node.js

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you need these things from the AWS account.
Access Key ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Secret Access Key: XXXXXXXXXXX
region= XXXXXXXXXXX (us-east-1)

After that use these parameters with your technology for uploading the image in s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

[Uploading Files to AWS S3 with Node.js](https://stackabuse.com/uploading-files-to-aws-s3-with-node-js/)

I am sorry but it's the first link from google :(